# DBGrid->OnColExit() focus fails

Tags: delphi, c++builder, vcl

```
void __fastcall TUsers::DBGColExit(TObject *Sender)
{
    Ado->ExecSQL();
    AQ4->Close();AQ4->Open();
}
```

after changing content of Table for AQ4 (Ado Query) and reload AQ4
DBG (DBGrid) reloads content too.

but I'm still on **not Exit from my Col** (Column) (and row) and then when I press on Selected+1 **after reload** row it selects second row of Grid, if I press Selected+2 it selects third row.

My selected item is first but not first in the same time.

> example : DBGrid contains **1 2 3 4
>   5** I select **4** and reload stuff
>   Then I click on **5** Selects **2**
>   And I just can't click on **1 2 3 4**
>   After reload.

how to fix this bug...

thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I seriously think "OnColExit" is not the place for what you're doing.

That aside, the behaviour you're describing does not seem to be a bug. By re-opening the dataset you're landing on the first record (navigate with the keyboard instead of the mouse and you'll see what I mean), while the grid thinks it's the column what have been changed.

You should at least try to stay on the same row, by utilizing a bookmark for instance. Delphi equivalent code would be sth. like this;

```
var
  Bookmark: TBookmark;
begin
  Bookmark := AQ4.GetBookmark;
  try

    [...] // close, open the query

    if AQ4.BookmarkValid(Bookmark) then
      AQ4.GotoBookmark(Bookmark);
  finally
    AQ4.FreeBookmark(Bookmark);
  end;
```